# Latex - picture color and minted color

Tags: color, minted, tikz-styles

I'm using `minted` package. If logo (top-picture) contains **green**, code color change.

```
\definecolor{codecolor}{RGB}{108,247,10}
\newminted{cpp}{linenos,bgcolor=codecolor!25,frame=lines,fontsize=\small,framerule=0.7pt,xleftmargin=20pt,mathescape}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[CO,CE]{\includegraphics[height=0.6in]{logo}}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\bfseries APIO .....}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\bfseries ......}
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
```

Look, pictures. First picture's logo don't contain green and code color is true.

[image]

But, second picture's logo contains green, so code color is false.

[image]

If I change logo, problem fixed.

How can we solve this problem?

Comment: Which format (pdf,png,jpg) is your logo stored in?

Comment: png format (all logos)

Comment: To help here we'll need a full example